# Jquery file upload progress finished too fast

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a progress bar with jquery. My code looks like this:

```
$('#post-form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#new-post-spinner').removeClass('hidden');

    if(image == null) {
        alert('Je hebt nog geen afbeelding geupload');
        $('#new-post-spinner').addClass('hidden');
        return;
    }

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', image);
    formData.append('dogs', selectedDogs);
    formData.append('body', $('#post-body').val());

    $.ajax({
        xhr: function() {
            var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();

            xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
                if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                    var percentComplete = ((evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100);
                    console.log(percentComplete);
                }
            }, false);

            return xhr;
        },
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/api/posts',
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
    });
});
```

Right now I `console.log` the progress. However, it's already 100% when the request isn't even finished. How is this possible? Because now the progress bar is obviously useless. I'm using the latest jquery version `3.5.1`.

Comment: A few possibilities come to mind: XHR has two components: the request and the response (and any delay in between). You might be able to tell in dev tools network pane if the 100% corresponds with the upload completion, and the unfinished part is the wait and response. If that's not it, my next guess would be that the browser may do some upload buffering or something.

Comment: can you please tell us which browsers you have tested so far?

Comment: I've done tests in safari, chrome and firefox. In every browser I've got the same problem. Very weird

Comment: I am not sure, but it could simply be that for any fraction between 0 & 1 `evt.loaded / evt.total` is returning an integer , ie 1. Try this instead `(Math.round((sent / total) * 1000) / 10)`